# People will run to The hills

Tags: grammar

If I say "people who watch this will run to the hills",

1. are you becoming curious of "the" here, or
2. will you understand perfectly what it meant, or
3. You would guess the speaker's own secret information and think "I am ok even if I am in the dark, since the speaker knows what he was talking abot?

(Let's not clarify "this" for now)

Comment: This only makes sense because of the idiom _make for the hills_. As often with idioms, there is _some_ variability - "run to" for "make for" - but it doesn't work if you change "the", or replace "hills" with "mountains"

Comment: Isn't it usually _head for the hills_?

Answer (score 1):

I would assume you were using the idiom "run for the hills" (which means to flee a disaster) but you were being hyperbolic and not literal.  So I'd assume that "this" was either something so terrible that people would run away from it:

> Run for the hills! CBS is showing the Star Wars Holiday Special!!

or it was a program about a looming disaster

> If watch the documentary about COVID21 you'll run for the hills.  It will be a lot worse than COVID19.

I would not think it was used literally, unless "this" was a tsunami warning.